# Publishing a project (ASP.NET) to Azure, still shows standard Azure page

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to publish my visual studio (2015) project to azure. When it's uploaded it says that the publish succeeded, but when I'm redirected, I still get the standard Azure page:
[image]

**Visual studio shows this:**
[image]
[image]

Comment: Your static files seem to be there - http://burgerschoolafspraken.azurewebsites.net/Situaties/stylesituaties.css, so it could be you just need to Restart your Web App from the Portal. Normally, there should not be a need for this. You can check what files have been deployed with Kudu - `https://{site}.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`

Comment: It seems that you don't set default page on the azure portal.

Comment: Do you have a default page? (heh, Tom beat me by 4 seconds!)

Comment: Hi both thanks for the answer, I thought so but I don't really know how to do that (I'm a student and azure is new for me). Could you help me with this please? Thanks on advance

Comment: I have updated the answer, more details please refer to it

Answer (score 1):

According to your description that files are uploaded, you also can check that with kudu tool(https://yourwebsite.scm.azurewebsites.net).

> I thought so but I don't really know how to do that

1.Login to [Azure portal](http://portal.azure.com)

2.select the [Application settings] blade to add the default page you wanted.

More details please refer to the screenshot to add default page.

[image]

**Edit:**

Please remove the **hostingstart.html** file from the default documents on the Azure portal and clear browse cache or with private mode to visit your site. Or use another browser to try again.

We also can  check **Remove additional files at destination** button during republish.
That will remove the files existing in the WebApp before upload the files.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, should I delete the ones above or not? Because I still get the standard page atm.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking, too :-)

Comment: `should I delete the ones above or not? Because I still get the standard page`  Please have a try to delete iisstart.htm.

Comment: Hi, thanks again. I did what you said but still the standard page though :(

Comment: Please make sure that the default page is in your website, how to use kudu please refer to the [blog](http://www.jamessturtevant.com/posts/How-to-add-edit-and-remove-files-in-your-azure-webapp-using-the-kudu-service-dashboard/).